# Python command to stop and start windows services ?

Tags: python-3.x

what is the python command to stop and start windows services.I can't use  win32serviceutil because am using latest python version 3.6.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `sc` command line interface provided by Windows:

```
import subprocess
# start the service
args = ['sc', 'start', 'Service Name']
result = subprocess.run(args)
# stop the service
args[1] = 'stop'
result = subprocess.run(args)
```

Comment: I have to admit that i tried this solution and i've been getting return code 1052 from windows

Answer (score 4):

The existing answer is very unpythonic and not simple enough.

I was searching for a Pythonic solution and stumbled upon this question.

I have a much simpler solution that isn't Pythonic.

Just use `net start servicename` with `os.system`.

For example, if we want to start MySQL80:

```py
import os
os.system('net start MySQL80')
```

Now using it as a function:

```py
import os

def start_service(svc):
    os.system(f'net start {svc}')
```

And to stop the service, use `net stop servicename`:

```py
import os

def stop_service(svc):
    os.system(f'net stop {svc}')
```

I know my solution isn't Pythonic but the existing answer also isn't Pythonic and so far in my Google searching I haven't found anything both relevant and Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Install `pywin32` [from GitHub](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/latest), there's no limitation regarding Python 3.6 in there(2017, I know) + it works directly with the Win32 API, so no `os.system()` or similar command calling. Also, no need for compiling, the author supplies the binaries in an installer. And there doesn't seem to be any issue with PyPI as well - [the versions are matching](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files).

Use the [`StartService(serviceName, args = None, machine = None)`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/e0a7d99d7fe770e6eda58c1fa0988e7cc48f9b97/win32/Lib/win32serviceutil.py#L411) function.